# How to optimize these FOR loops to save execution time in Matlab script

Tags: arrays, matlab, multidimensional-array, indexing, nested-loops

I want to know if there is a way to do this large data set calculations without the for loops.

My WarpVec is a large 5 dimensional array with a great deal of data inside.

My algorithm compares the 3 spaces next to the current space (can be a NaN or any real value) to check if the surrounding 3 cells are opposite the current space.  Pretty much if the center space is NaN and the 3 neighbors are non NaN values then I draw a flag, and vice versa when center is non NaN value and its 3 neighbors are NaN values.

What if any are my options here?  Is there a way to index this better?  Can I use some vector analysis somewhere to cut back the run time?

```
for X = 1:size(WarpVec, 1)
    for L = 1:size(WarpVec, 2)   
        for k = 1:size(WarpVec,3)
            for i = 2:(size(WarpVec, 4)-1)
                for j = 2:(size(WarpVec, 5)-1)
                    tri1(X, L, k, i, j) = ~isnan(WarpVec(X, L, k, i, j)) && (~isnan(WarpVec(X, L, k, i-1, j-1))...
                                         || ~isnan(WarpVec(X, L, k, i, j-1)) || ~isnan(WarpVec(X, L, k, i-1, j)))...
                                         || (~isnan(WarpVec(X, L, k, i-1, j-1)) && ~isnan(WarpVec(X, L, k, i, j-1))...
                                         && ~isnan(WarpVec(X, L, k, i-1, j)));

                    tri2(X, L, k, i, j) = ~isnan(WarpVec(X, L, k,  i, j)) && (~isnan(WarpVec(X, L, k,  i, j-1))... 
                                          || ~isnan(WarpVec(X, L, k,  i+1, j-1)) || ~isnan(WarpVec(X, L, k,  i+1, j)))...
                                          || (~isnan(WarpVec(X, L, k,  i, j-1)) && ~isnan(WarpVec(X, L, k,  i+1, j-1))...
                                          && ~isnan(WarpVec(X, L, k,  i+1, j)));

                    tri3(X, L, k, i, j) = ~isnan(WarpVec(X, L, k,  i,j)) && (~isnan(WarpVec(X, L, k,  i-1, j))...
                                          || ~isnan(WarpVec(X, L, k,  i-1, j+1)) || ~isnan(WarpVec(X, L, k,  i, j+1)))...
                                          || (~isnan(WarpVec(X, L, k,  i-1, j)) && ~isnan(WarpVec(X, L, k,  i-1, j+1))...
                                          && ~isnan(WarpVec(X, L, k,  i, j+1)));

                    tri4(X, L, k, i, j) = ~isnan(WarpVec(X, L, k,  i,j)) && (~isnan(WarpVec(X, L, k,  i+1, j))...
                                         || ~isnan(WarpVec(X, L, k,  i+1, j+1)) || ~isnan(WarpVec(X, L, k,  i, j+1)))...
                                         || (~isnan(WarpVec(X, L, k,  i+1, j)) && ~isnan(WarpVec(X, L, k,  i+1, j+1))...
                                         && ~isnan(WarpVec(X, L, k,  i, j+1)));
                end
            end
        end 
     end
end
```

First time posting here.  Thanks for any and all help.  I greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Let's take out last two for loops, by using boolean indexing:

```
tri1=true(size(WarpVec, 1), size(WarpVec, 2), size(WarpVec,3), size(WarpVec,4), size(WarpVec,5);
tri2=tri1;% same for tri3 and tri4.
for X = 1:size(WarpVec, 1)
    for L = 1:size(WarpVec, 2)   
        for k = 1:size(WarpVec,3)
                    tri1(X, L, k, ~isnan(WarpVec(X, L, k, :, :)) & (~isnan(WarpVec(X, L, k, [1,1:end-1], [1,1:end-1]))...
                                         | ~isnan(WarpVec(X, L, k, :, [1,1:end-1])) | ~isnan(WarpVec(X, L, k, [1,1:end-1], :)))...
                                         | (~isnan(WarpVec(X, L, k, [1,1:end-1], [1,1:end-1])) & ~isnan(WarpVec(X, L, k, :, [1,1:end-1]))...
                                         & ~isnan(WarpVec(X, L, k, [1,1:end-1], :))))=true;

                    tri2(X, L, k, ~isnan(WarpVec(X, L, k, :, :)) & (~isnan(WarpVec(X, L, k, :, [1,1:end-1]))... 
                                          | ~isnan(WarpVec(X, L, k, [2:end,end], [1,1:end-1])) | ~isnan(WarpVec(X, L, k, [2:end,end], :)))...
                                          | (~isnan(WarpVec(X, L, k, :, [1,1:end-1])) & ~isnan(WarpVec(X, L, k, [2:end,end], [1,1:end-1]))...
                                          & ~isnan(WarpVec(X, L, k,  i+1, j))))=true;

 %same for tri3, tri4.
        end 
     end
end
```

If you have sufficiently ram, you may also use that even faster form:

```
isw=isnan(WarpVec);    
tri1=~isw(:,:,:, :, :) & (~isw(:,:,:, [1,1:end-1], [1,1:end-1])...
| ~isw(:,:,:, :, [1,1:end-1]) | ~isw(:,:,:, [1,1:end-1], :)...
| (~isw(:,:,:, [1,1:end-1], [1,1:end-1])) & ~isw(:,:,:, :, [1,1:end-1])...
                                         & ~isw(:,:,:, [1,1:end-1], :));
```